# I am getting this error while doing simple toggle program

Tags: javascript, html, css

[I don't why I am getting this error, My JS code is running fine directly in the console of my browser but when I am trying to attach a .js file to my html I get this error.[][1]1

[://i.stack.imgur.com/wON7T.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ7Pe.jpg)

```
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");
var isPurple = false;

button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(isPurple){
        document.body.style.background = "white";
        isPurple = false;
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "purple";
        isPurple = true;
    }
});




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="MyTitle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you placed the `script` tag in your `html`? In the `head` tag or in the `body` tag after the content?

Comment: move `<script src="MyTitle.js"></script>` after `<button>click me</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tHe code supplied seems to work fine - as noted int the comments - where you place the external js - make sa difference - it should be placed at the end of the code - just before the closing body tag. As a rule - place all the external CSS files in the head and all external js files in the body - unless there  is some rendering based logic that is required in the javascript.

In this case - the javascript is intended to identify the button using the querySelector() - but it is not in the DOM yet so cannot be identified.

Also - you can simplify your code and just toggle the variable on the  click and then use a ternary for adding / romoving a class with the background color set to the class. Its always better to use classes with styling attached rather than amendifing the CSS via the javascript.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");
var isPurple = false;

button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isPurple = !isPurple;

  isPurple 
   ? document.body.classList.add('purple')
   : document.body.classList.remove('purple')
});
```

```css
.purple {
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>
    <script src="MyTitle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course - you could actually  remove the variable totally - its always better if you can move away from global variables when possible - the following simply toggles the class on the button click.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector("button");


button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.classList.toggle('purple')
});
```

```css
.purple {
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="MyTitle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>
    <script src="MyTitle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad I could help -happy coding 

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the time the JavaScript is run the button element does not yet exist in the DOM. Load it afterwards and it should then exist OK.

In general it is wise to load such JS, i.e. that is going to run immediately on load, at the end OR put it into a window.onload function (especially if the code relies on images being already loaded).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>
<script src="MyTitle.js"></script> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hee hee - thats what I already posted as an answer - its a race in here to give the solution first :)

Comment: @gavgrif I should have checked whether there was an answer before posting, I was just testing mine. Your solution is of course fine. Quite fun to think of SO as a race!